# Laravel How to Test _Constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm

I have a constructor in my controller. I want to test how many times it's initialized. Is there a way to do it in Laravel 5.7?

Comment: As far as I know there is not, but I would recommend you tanking a look at the Factory Pattern, it can suit your needs.

Comment: @namelivia I see, thanks for the advice.